# Azure Log analytics : Error while configuring custom data

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to configure collection of custom logs using log analytics in azure. I connected my linux VM to OMS workspace and also installed Linux agent in my VM. but after this Whenever I try to go to  "CustomData" menu under  Log Analytics workspace\Advance Settings following error pops up

Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "value". Array position index expected.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test in my lab, I get the same error log with you.

[image]

I will give a feedback to Azure.

You could configure it on OMS portal. I test in my lab, in OMS portal, I don't get the error log.

[image]

Comment: How to configure that in OMS portal. is configuring OMS portal only possible through portal or it can be done using arm template or scripts also.

Comment: You want to connect your VM to OMS?

Comment: what about doing configuration through ARM template or azure cli?? I am not able to find ny link to that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162078/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-blindsniper).

Comment: Maybe you could check this template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-template-workspace-configuration

Comment: I created one custom log but OMS is not collecting it.As i cannot see any log files in list.These are simple txt files where can I find them

Comment: @BlindSniper Could you share your policy? But I think it is a different question. Maybe you could ask a new question about your policy and your issue. I am very glad to answer it.