# Azure Log Analytics 403 error

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics

Getting error 403 whenever I'm trying to save any changes in the Advanced setting of the Azure Log Analytics.

I'm the owner of the subscription and still getting this error.Please check to attached file for more clarity.

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a know issue in Azure. You could do it on OMS Portal.

[image]

Comment: You could see the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003552/azure-log-analytics-error-while-configuring-custom-data).

Comment: Hi Shengbao, thanks for the solution.
Do you know how can I setup cpu,memory,network and disk alert using the log analytics or reference me to a link which does that ?

Comment: If my understanding is right, you find this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-performance-counters).

Comment: About alter rule, you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-alerts-creating). Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Shengbao, I'm a bit confused with the log search commands.
I think there should a log search in order to create a rule first.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue but using the OMS portal or PowerShell gives error bad request error.
Any guidance you could share here?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/582b2f66-670e-4b57-8118-a1bbf5092d7d/log-analytics-workspace-giving-403-or-forbidden-error-when-engaging-details-to-the-resource-is?forum=opinsights

Comment: Hi Michael, my issue got resolved after I started making change from the OMS dashboard.
Hope it does same for you.

Comment: Hi the issue is resolved by itself now, the service is again responding, without any interaction, not to comforting but most likely being dealt with. Still would be nice to know the root cause.